# Error Setting up administrator account on selfhosted confluence

Tags: centos, confluence, self-hosting

I m setting up confluence from Centos 7. I have completed the installation but stuck with error while try to create an admin account from the browser. It looks like a captcha error while authenticating. I need help to by pass this error to create a default admin account. See screenshots and error logs below

Image on selecting mode of user-management. I pick Internal confluence user management

I supplied my default admin details by filling the form

Form to select mode of managing users. I picked Manage Users and groups with confluence[image: Form to select mode of managing users. I picked Manage Users and groups with confluence]

Fill the signup form and it has no captcha[image: Fill the signup form and it has no captcha]

The error screenshot[image: Error sceenshot]

The Java Error Stack Trace from the browser

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.actions.SetupAdministrator.validate(SetupAdministrator.java:47)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.core.ConfluenceWorkflowInterceptor.intercept(ConfluenceWorkflowInterceptor.java:18)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.security.interceptors.CaptchaInterceptor.intercept(CaptchaInterceptor.java:42)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.xwork.interceptors.XsrfTokenInterceptor.intercept(XsrfTokenInterceptor.java:120)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.xwork.ConfluenceXsrfTokenInterceptor.intercept(ConfluenceXsrfTokenInterceptor.java:30)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.core.ConfluenceLicenseInterceptor.intercept(ConfluenceLicenseInterceptor.java:65)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.validation.MessageHolderInterceptor.intercept(MessageHolderInterceptor.java:37)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.util.LoggingContextInterceptor.intercept(LoggingContextInterceptor.java:44)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.core.CancellingInterceptor.intercept(CancellingInterceptor.java:21)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.xwork.interceptors.RestrictHttpMethodInterceptor.intercept(RestrictHttpMethodInterceptor.java:119)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.security.websudo.WebSudoInterceptor.intercept(WebSudoInterceptor.java:34)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.themes.ThemeContextInterceptor.intercept(ThemeContextInterceptor.java:35)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.security.actions.PermissionCheckInterceptor.intercept(PermissionCheckInterceptor.java:97)
> at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
> at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.webwork.BootstrapAwareInterceptor.intercept(BootstrapAwareInterceptor.java:19)

Answer (score 0):

Since database is not specified, it will be a general answer for such cases. Also error traces are not always show exactly what can be wrong.

There are a variety of potential issues which can be. Most common are:

- incorrect permissions on database (it's important to have database user as its owner, confluence 6.x version failed with such error). [Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-datasource-connection-937166084.html) you can find how to set up a db correctly for different dbs
- incorrect folders permissions (**confluence_home** - by default it's `/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence` and **confluence_install** which is by default is `/opt/atlassian/confluence`).

All other potential issues and its resolutions can be found on [Atlassian kb related to troubleshooting starting issues](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-does-not-start-due-to-spring-application-context-has-not-been-set-218278311.html)